# FutureTask never completes

Tags: java, future, executorservice

In the below code, the if loop is not getting executed. Before the futureTask1 and 2 gets completed, the next line of code is executed. And, the program never terminates. What is my error, here?

```
    ExecutorService executor=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    MyClass1 myclass1= new MyClass1(x,y);
    MyClass2 myclass2= new MyClass2(x,y);

    FutureTask<List<String>> futureTask1 = new FutureTask<List<String>>(myclass1);
    FutureTask<List<String>> futureTask2 = new FutureTask<List<String>>(myclass2);

    executor.submit(futureTask1);
    executor.submit(futureTask2);

    System.out.println("FutureTask completed");

    if(futureTask1.isDone() && futureTask2.isDone()){
        System.out.println("Done");
        //shut down executor service
        executor.shutdown();
        //Execute some code
        return;
    }
```

Comment: How do you **know** that "FutureTask completed" message is correct...? I mean, the task(s) actually completed?

Comment: What is your 'if loop'? I can't see any **loop** in the code presented...

Comment: Yes. That's what I want. I need to wait for it to get completed before executing the next line.

Comment: So: `while( !futureTask1.isDone() || !futureTask2.isDone()) {} System.out.println("Done");` should do.

Answer (score 0):

You're submitting your tasks to the executor, but I'm not seeing any code that waits for the executor to finish the tasks.  `executor.submit()` should return you a `Future` which you can use to wait for your task.